# System of numbers $\{\pm i^2: i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ generates $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I ran into very interesting problem on contest math after some thoughts I came up with a solution.

Prove that any positive integer can be represented as $\pm 1^2\pm2^2\pm\dots\pm n^2$ for some positive integer $n$ and some choice of the signs.

In other words, $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists n=n(k)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\varepsilon_i i^2$, where $\varepsilon \in \{-1,+1\}$.

**Proof:** We'll use the strong math induction.

For $k=1$ we can write $k=1^2$

For $k=2$ we can write $k=-1^2-2^2-3^2+4^2$

For $k=3$ we can write $k=-1^2+2^2$

For $k=4$ we can write $k=-1^2-2^2+3^2$

Cases $k\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ are the base case.

Suppose our statement is true for $1\leqslant m \leqslant k$ for $k\geqslant 4$.

Let's try to prove it for $m=k+1$.

Using our assumption we know that for $m=k$ there is the following representation: $k=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\varepsilon_i i^2$ and it's easy to establish the identity: $4=(n+1)^2-(n+2)^2-(n+3)^2+(n+4)^2$.
So adding the last two identities we get that: $k+4=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n+4}\varepsilon_i i^2$ where $\varepsilon_{n+1}=\varepsilon_{n+4}=1$ and $\varepsilon_{n+2}=\varepsilon_{n+3}=-1$. Thus if statement is true for $m=k$ then it is true for $m=k+4$.

Since $k\geqslant 4$ then $k-3\geqslant 1$ and $k-3<k$ then statement holds for $k-3$ then using above reasoning it follows that reasoning for $k+1$ also true.

Thus, we completely proved our statement (which in my opinion is quite interesting).

Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: So adding the last two identities we get that $k=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n+4}\varepsilon_i i^2$ - Did you mean $k+4$ on the left?

Comment: @B.Mehta, Yes exactly. Sorry. i'll edit right now

Answer (score 0):

The proof looks good to me! It might be cleaner to skip the $m=k+4$ step and just prove it for $m=k+1$, since that's all you need. Argue instead that you can represent $k-3$ and $4$, giving you $k+1$ as required.